# Zuul spring security and adding Additional Params in Request

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, microservices, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am building Microservices using Spring Microservices, I have 2 questions related to that.
1. I have spring security in the Api Gateway i.e **Zuul server**, now Zuul is not forwarding any request if I have already read the request from the stream once to Authenticate(to get username/pass from POST Request) 
`new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), UserDto.class);` 

**How can I read the request and then again forward the same request to Downstream services?**
2. Zuul is not forwarding **request.setAttribute()** to Downstream services, so a workaround is to use **ctx.addZuulRequestHeader**, which is making `Request Header` too huge, How can I acheive **request.setAttribute** and get in downstream services.

```
 public Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    final String token = request.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER_NAME);
    logger.info("token="+token);
    if (token != null) {
        logger.info("Entering getAuthentication");
        final UserToken userInfo = tokenHandler.validateToken(token);
        if (userInfo != null
                && token.equals(String.valueOf(redisUtility.getValue(userInfo.getUsername()+"_"+userInfo.getUniqueId())))) {
            logger.info("Validating token key="+userInfo.getUsername()+"_"+userInfo.getUniqueId());
            User user=userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userInfo.getUsername());
            if(user!=null && user.getUsername().equals(userInfo.getUsername())
                && user.getLastPasswordResetTime()<userInfo.getCreatedTime()){
                request.setAttribute("username",user.getUsername());//**Not able to fetch this in Downstream services**
                logger.info("Token Authenticated for User "+user.getUsername());
                return new UserAuthentication(user);
            }
        } 
    }
    return null;
}


  public class SimpleFilter extends ZuulFilter {

      private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleFilter.class);

      @Override
      public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
      }

      @Override
      public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
        request.setAttribute("test", "test");// Not able to get this in services
        log.info(String.format("%s request to %s", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURL().toString()));

        return null;
      }

 @Bean
  public SimpleFilter simpleFilter() {
    return new SimpleFilter();
  }

@RequestMapping(value = "/test/avl",method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String test(HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println(request.getAttribute("test")+"");
    return "Spring in Action";
  }
```

Comment: if I am not wrong you will have to write a pre filter to do the stuff that you are looking for try to go thru this https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/Writing-Filters it might help.

Comment: @Grinish even if i set attributes in Filter i am not able get those in services as request.getAttribute().

Comment: i have the same thing in my code i add attributes to the request and receive it downstream which is working  can you add the code for your filter if you have one already...

Comment: @Grinish Does it really matters where u add in Zuul filter or anywhere else, I am adding  the request.setAttribute() in one of my Spring Auth Filters, but I tried same in Zuul filter too. So, if you just add request.setAttribute("test","test"), were you able to get in downstream, any special configs in yml?

Comment: @Grinish I added the code which is a Spring filter.

Comment: I have the attribute being added in zuul pre filter and yes i was able to receive test in the downstream services. The spring filter seems alrite to me try using zuul filter since you need to play with the request within zuul rather than spring filter. Also when using Zuul filter donot forget to declare the @bean in the class that has enablezuulproxy annotation. also no special changes in yml file only thing i donot use spring security so disabled that using security.basic.enabled: false.

Comment: @Grinish No its not working. I tried all possibilities. Can you paste your code where you are doing this.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's 1 year late. But for any new visitors.

create a filter.

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFilter extends ZuulFilter {
    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

        ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("userId", "123456789");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Annotate it with @Component, so it will be automatically loaded. Inside run method, use `addZuulRequestHeader`

Comment: This would not work if you want to add  authorization or authentication header.
If you need to add these headers you need to add `sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie`  to the `application.properties`

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3394#issuecomment-665603169